# Bose–Einstein statistics exercise

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, quantum-statistics

I've a basic Bose–Einstein statistics exercise. I've tried to solve it in two ways, but each way gives a different result.

We have $n$ identical bosons without interactions at temperature $T$. There are two states, of energies $\epsilon > 0$ and $0$. The question is: What is the value of $U$?

- The first way is to say that the number of particles of the system is the sum of the average number of bosons for each energy :

$$n = \frac{1}{e^{\beta\epsilon-\alpha}-1}+\frac{1}{e^{-\alpha}-1}$$

Given $n$, we can obtain $\alpha = f(n)$ and finally say that

$$U = \frac{\epsilon}{e^{\beta\epsilon-f(n)}-1}$$

I've calculated $f$ (it is quite long...), and it doesn't give the same results than the second method.

- The second way is to say that

$$Z(\beta) = \sum_{n_0 + n_\epsilon = n} e^{-\beta n_\epsilon \epsilon} = \frac{1 - e^{-\beta\epsilon (n+1)}}{1-e^{-\beta \epsilon}}$$

and then

$$U = -\frac{\partial \ln Z}{\partial \beta}$$

In fact, I've seen the solution of the exercise and it is the second answer. But why is the first wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the chemical potential is zero.

Consider that, at all temperatures, there is a macroscopic population in the ground state, *i.e.*, the system is in a mixed phase with a BEC at all temperatures. The criteria for a BEC to form is $\mu=0$ ($\alpha/\beta$ in your notation). Thus, at all temperatures, $\alpha=0$.

Now, if you take the thermodynamic limit *viz.* $n\rightarrow\infty$, both your answers coincide. Your first answer remains unaltered save for setting $f(n)=0$, yielding
$$
U = \frac{\epsilon}{e^{\beta\epsilon}-1}.
$$

In the thermodynamic limit, your second answer becomes

$$
\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} Z(\beta) = \frac{1}{1-e^{-\beta\epsilon}}.
$$

Using $U=-\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}\ln{Z}$ yields

$$
\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}U = \frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}\ln{\left[1-e^{-\beta\epsilon}\right]}=\frac{\epsilon}{e^{\beta\epsilon}-1},
$$
the same as your first answer. QED

I think the discrepancy for finite $n$ arises due to inequivalency in particle number fluctuations between canonical and grand canonical ensembles for for finite $n$ ...

Answer (score 0):

In the first way, you are using grand-canonical ensemble (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_canonical_ensemble), with fixed temperature and chemical potential.

In this situation (grand-canonical ensemble), the number of particles is **not fixed.**

So it is in contradiction with you assertion of $n$ identical bosons, because you suppose here that the number of particles is fixed.

Comment: When you use The grand-canonical ensemble, the number of particles is not fixed. But your assertion of n identical bosons (so n fixed) is in contradiction with this. So it is incoherent.

Comment: So you have to choose, if you fix the number of bosons (n fixed), you cannot use the grand-canonical ensemble and chemical potential (your first way). If you choose to use grand-canonical ensemble, you cannot fix the number of particles.

Comment: I think that we can use the grand canonical ensemble even if the number of particles is not fixed. Could somebody confirm ?

Comment: (Sorry, my previous comment had a typo) I think that we can use the grand canonical ensemble even if the number of particles is fixed. Could somebody confirm ?

Comment: @Arnaud Your expression for average n comes from a geometric series with n running from 0 to infinity for each energy level. Although people sometimes impose fixed N for this ensemble (e.g. https://ps.uci.edu/~cyu/p115A/LectureNotes/Lecture13/lecture13.pdf), I suspect that this N must be interpreted as the "average total number of bosons". In a given time, the system may have more than N bosons and later it will have less, such that average number of bosons is N. Right now, I can't conceive another way of having your expression for average n with fixed N.